Jquery error on the ScriptResource.axd file
In my aspx page there is textbox to do search which have onkeyup event.Onkeyp event method is get called but Whenever type text on that textbox, get the below jquery error on the page.

I am not sure what this error is about and why it is throwing cannot read properties of null. And due to this error textbox loose the focus after type the text and need to click on textbox again to do search again.
